# In Git Bash, how can I spawn a new cmd window?

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

I'm aware that I can execute `cmd` commands in Git Bash by just running

```
cmd.exe //c <command>
```

This way, the commands will run in the Git Bash window.

However, I'd like to spawn a new cmd window to execute my task. The reason for this is that Git Bash doesn't handle ANSI colour codes the way `cmd` does.

So how can I spawn a new `cmd` window in Git Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try start - so (trivial exammple)

```
start cmd //c
```